# SP list item - disable "Edit" for all users except for the item creator but still leave a single column editable for all users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Is it possible to use Item-level Permissions in SP 2013 to disable other users modifying items not created by them but still allow them to modify a single field (column) from that item?

I want everyone to be able to input information in that column after clicking "Edit" item button but yet not able to modify any other field if the item is not created by him.

Only the item creator should be able to modify all the fields.

Any ideas how to achieve that are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use client object model for the same as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(CheckCreatedBy() != GetCurrentUser())
{
      $("input[Title='EditableByAllUsers']").prop("disabled", true);
}

});  

function CheckCreatedBy()
{
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
var oList = siteColl.get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('ChangeEditForm');  
var itemId = _spGetQueryParam('id') ;
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>'+ itemId +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
 this.collListItem= oList.getItems(camlQuery);
 clientContext.load(collListItem);        
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onCheckCreatedBySuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCheckCreatedByFailureMethod));        
return this.value;
    }
function onCheckCreatedBySuccessMethod(sender, args)
{
var CreatedBy = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    CreatedBy =  oListItem.get_item('Author').get_lookupValue(); 
      alert(CreatedBy); 
      return CreatedBy ;
}
}
function onCheckCreatedByFailureMethod(sender, args)
{
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
}

function GetCurrentUser()
{
var ClientContext = new  SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.CurrentWeb = ClientContext.get_web();
ClientContext.load(this.CurrentWeb.get_currentUser());
ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));  
  return this.value;
  }  
   function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) 
{    
   var userObject =this.CurrentWeb.get_currentUser().get_title();       
    return userObject;
}  
function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {  
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
}
```

It can also be done using XSL. [This](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-current-user-name-using-xsl-and-parameterbinding/) will help you with the same.

I hope this helps.